# Помогите составить регулярное выражение в php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно сравнить переменную `$com`, которая принимает только целые положительные значения (по сути это счетчик). Должно заканчиваться на 1, но не на 11. То есть если `$com=1` возвращать `true`, если `$com=11` возвращать `false`, но при этом когда `$com=21` возвращать снова `true` Вроде бы составляю верно, но что-то упускаю.

```
 preg_match('/[^1]*1$/',$com);
```

Comment: А на 511 что должно возвращаться, false?

Comment: Да, а на 501 true. Это для алгоритма написания слова "комментарий" после числа. Снизу верный ответ подсказали

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться негативной ретроспективной проверкой, явно затребовав, чтобы перед последней цифрой 1, не было другой цифры 1

```
<?php
$com = '111';
echo preg_match('/(?<!1)1$/', $com);
```

Comment: напишите, что это хорошо еще тем, что $com = 1 пройдет, а в исходном варианте - нет

Comment: Помогло, только непонятен код, совсем. Не трудно пояснить?

Comment: Смотрите вот эта штука (?<! ...)x требует чтобы перед x не было выражения ... называется негативная ретроспективная проверка. Всего 4 типа таких проверок - позитивная/негативная, опережающая/ретроспективная проверки. Подробнее можно почитать либо тут https://habrahabr.ru/post/159483/, либо в книге Дж.Фридла Регулярные выражения.

Answer (score 0):

Квантификатор `*` допускает нулевое повторение символьного класса и является синонимом `{0,}`. Вот он и совпадает с нулем символов, за которым идет терминирующая единица. Вам, очевидно, нужен квантификатор `+` (хотя по условиям задачи он не нужен вообще).

Comment: ну мне как раз и надо 0 и более не единиц перед еденицей))). Я думал я это и написал

Comment: @ЖеняВеденин вы же понимаете, что `11` в данном случае может трактоваться как последовательность "одна единица, ноль не-единиц, одна единица"?

Comment: )))) Видимо нет) Спасибо